# concatenate two integers in hexa and save them in long long int C

Tags: c

How can I concatenate two integers and save the data in `long long int`,

Example:

```
int x=0x1234abcd;
int y=0x5678cdef;
```

the result is,

`long long z=0x1234abcd5678cdef`;

Comment: `z = ((long long) x << 32) + y`?

Comment: yes now it is working, thank you, but it is (or | ) not (+)   z=((long long) x<<32) | y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code

```
int main(void) {
        int x = 0x1234abcd;
        int y = 0x5678cdef;
        long long z = ((long long)x<<32) | y;/* x needs to be type casted as long long */
        printf("%llx\n",z);
        return 0;

}
```

Also take consideration of `x` or `y` being negative number i.e if `sign` bit is `set(1)`. It's better to declare type as `unsigned` as pointed by @harold.

Comment: `(long long)x<<32` is UB when `x < 0`.  `printf("%llx\n",z)` with is also UB when `z < 0`. Recommend to use _unsigned_ math for this task.  `

Comment: @chux why is the shift UB? It cannot change the sign, since the top 32 bits are copies of the sign of `x`

Comment: Left shifting negative values is UB per C11 §6.5.7 4, even it it very commonly  "works" as desired.  Perhaps if you cannot find a related post, post the question.

Comment: @chux I see. How about if it's changed to a multiplication?

Comment: `0x100000000LL * x + y;` may be sufficient.  Still using unsigned values and types would simplify matters.  It is unclear why OP is using `int` with _hexadecimal constants_.  Had problem been `x=0xabcd1234;  y=0xcdef5678;`, unsigned math would readily be seen as a better approach.